# Mercurial - close default branch and replace with a named branch as new default

Tags: mercurial, branching-and-merging

In a mercurial repo, the "default" branch has fallen very out of date to the point where it no longer makes sense to merge in the changes from "develop", a named branch which has the latest deployed version of the application.

Instead of merging develop into default, how can I close the current default branch and then create a new default branch using the head from develop?

I've seen a few other questions and answers which are similar, perhaps the same, but I am still having trouble understanding how this should work.

Thanks!

Comment: alternatively, you could `update` to default and `merge` with develop, but before committing the merge you make it an exact copy of develop.

Comment: That would actually work, but how can I do that?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If `default` has diverged somewhat from `develop` and you want `default` to be exactly the same as `develop` after the merge, you need a slightly different set of commands from what Edward gave you (this will also work where `develop` is a direct descendant of `default`).

```
hg update -C default
hg -y merge --tool internal:fail develop
hg revert --all --no-backup -r develop
hg resolve --all --mark
hg commit -m "merge updating default to current develop"
```

This means that any conflicts will result in an unresolved merge. You then revert *everything* to be the same as on the `develop` branch (with no backup so you don't get lots of .orig files left over).

Comment: Tim this worked perfectly. Thanks for your help! By going through both your answer as well as Edward's I just learned a lot about hg.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment that it is not a requirement to close the branch, here's a series of steps that should get the default branch in tune with the develop branch:

1. `hg update default`
2. `hg merge --tool internal:other` -- to merge while privileging the develop branch
3. `hg diff -r develop` -- compare with develop to ensure that you have an exact copy
4. `hg commit -m "merge updating default to current develop"`

Once complete, you should have an updated default that mirrors the develop branch, bringing them back into sync.

Comment: Edward thank you for the answer.  I tested out your process and got the following result on step 2: abort: branch 'default' has one head - please merge with an explicit rev.  In my repo there are more then  2 heads due to several other active named branches. Anyways, this initial solution clearly got the ball rolling so thanks again. Also the hg diff -r is useful command which I have not seen before.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use a concept in Tortoisehg to explain how it works.

- `hg update` to develop branch
- choose the head of default branch, and choose merge with local
- then choose discard all changes from merge target (other), thus default is merged into develop without affecting the develop
- then branch to default from the head of develop, use `hg branch default`, default restarts again