# How to perform multi-stage and/or multi-developer merge in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, merge, workflow

The problem is following:

We have `default` and `feature` branch and at some point we have to bring changes from `default` to `feature` branch.

The changes are numerous and cannot be merged by one team member because the different changes were introduced by different people and the conflicts that are numerous need to be resolved by the people who introduced them.

Is it possible to perform multiple stage merge so that everybody on the team resolves their own conflicts on their workstation using some mechanism within the Mercurial itself?

Any idea how to do it other then put everyone into one office on one computer and lock them up until they are finished?

Comment: Is it possible to make a partial merge (of your own stuff) SHELVE the working dir, send shelve to a colleague, and somehow enable him to continue the merge?

Comment: Is there a way to display/merge only the changes made on the default branch from certain changeset? (The repository is a convert from CVS. We had merged the changes from HEAD 15 days ago, so only a small number of changesets remain to be merged. I'm getting the feeling that we are missing something)

Answer (score 1):

You can merge specific changesets from one branch to another. If you're willing to to do them in order you can just use `hg merge` one after another - but that will require scheduling the developers. Identify a range of changesets that should be merged (from when the default and feature branches divererged), identify the developer that should merge them. Do the merges in sequence.

If the changes from the various developers are independent then you could also use `hg graft` which would allow a more parallel merge. Each developer would graft their sets of changes to the feature branch, and then you would do a final `hg merge` (which may be a no-op) to finish everything up.

In both cases it might be easiest to branch one or more merge branches off the feature branch and merge/graft to there, resolve any issues, then merge that branch to the feature branch.

Comment: I think that the first option of Tim's is your best option here. To avoid getting into this situation again, you really should merge more frequently.

Comment: @SteveKaye I know we should merge more frequently, but as I said in other comment, we imported the project from CVS (finally). I wonder is there a way to merge just the changes made to default and skip over those from feature branch?

Comment: I'm confused. In one comment you say there are only a small number of merges remaining (after merging from HEAD), in another you say there are too many changesets. And I don't know what you mean by that last comment - do you want the feature branch to end up identical to default? In that case look at my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984793/mercurial-close-default-branch-and-replace-with-a-named-branch-as-new-default/14991454#14991454.

Comment: there is now 90 changesets, but not the number of changesets matter, its the number of changes/conflicts whats problematic. The problem is that this repo was imported from CVS, and feature branch is 400 changesets long. Numerous changes are there because the feature branch is not yet merged with default.